# Xamarin.iOS registration issue?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

When running on my device (iPhone6+) I am getting the below error when I execute the following line of code:

```
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(value, preference);
```

I get this error:

```
The ObjectiveC class 'NSUserDefaults' could not be registered, it does not seem to derive from any known ObjectiveC class (including NSObject).
```

Comment: This works just fine for me, so it's not as simple as it sounds. I suggest you file a bug (http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) with a complete solution that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I was calling this before UIApplication.Main(args). I am assuming that is the problem.

Comment: Likely, several things do not work (well or at all) before `UIApplicationMain` is called.

Comment: Yes. This was a bit of a red herring